# How is a css layout made fluid?

Tags: android, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fluid

So I've been lately stumbling a lot on fluid layout vs fixed and layout and stuff, and I am making an attempt to make my website's layout fluid.

even though twitter-bootstrap provides some fluid class for almost every element in my html, I'd like to customize it on my own.

After reading some articles, I kinda get it this way

```
@media(1321px){
/*Code for 1321px screens*/
}

@media(800px){
/*code for 800px*/
}
```

am I right? should I just put the styles I want for every screen's resolution and that's how you get fluid layout?

Comment: use `@media all and (max-width:1321px)`

Comment: If I do this, will I be able to customize -let's say my sidebar- to shrink on smaller screens? please provide in the answer's section an answer if you can .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fluid layout is when everything resizes to fit the window.

```
.container {
  width: 100%;
}
```

Fixed layout is when widths of container elements are fixed (don't change).

```
.container {
  width: 800px;
}
```

The @media() tag is used for responsive design. Which usually mixes fixed and fluid layouts. Eg. fluid for small devices, fixed for large screens.

```
/* all screen sizes */
.container {
  width: 100%;
}

/* screens 1000px and up */
@media(min-width: 1000px){
  .container {
    width: 1000px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Absolutely thanks!. How about the behavior of some sidebars, they shrink and hide text, and they're suddenly just icons.. Is this attainable via JavaScript or just plain css?

Comment: @TECHPUSHTA a mix of both

Comment: It can be done with css @media queries. Checkout [twitter bootstrap visibile/hidden classes](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Answer (score 1):

actually it's not mediaqueries that make a website "fluid". a fluid layout is based on percentage widths instead of pixels, or a mix of both (fixed widths for certain elements is not prohibited or considered a bad practice).

you should make a fluid architecture, stretch or narrow your browser window (depending if you are designing desktop or mobile first) and (quote):

> when your design looks like shit, add a `mediaquery`

http://bradfrostweb.com/blog/post/7-habits-of-highly-effective-media-queries/